# WCF Proxy Class Not Generating As Object Parameter

Tags: c#, wcf

When I define the below Operation Contract in the WCF Service:-

```
public void SaveEmployee(EmployeeInfo employee)
{

    string cs = ConfigurationManager.ConnectionStrings["EMS"].ConnectionString;

    using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(cs))
    {
        SqlCommand cmd = new SqlCommand("spSaveEmployee",con);
        cmd.CommandType = CommandType.StoredProcedure;
        SqlParameter parameterId = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Id", Value = employee.Id };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterId);
        SqlParameter parameterName = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Name", Value = employee.Name };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterName);
        SqlParameter parameterGender = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@Gender", Value = employee.Gender };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterGender);
        SqlParameter parameterDOB = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@DateOfBirth", Value = employee.DOB };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterDOB);
        SqlParameter parameterType = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@EmployeeType", Value = employee.Type };
        cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterType);

        if (employee.Type == EmployeeType.FullTimeEmployee)
        {
            SqlParameter parameterAnnualSalary = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@AnnualSalary", Value = employee.AnnualSalary };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterAnnualSalary);
        }
        else
        {
            SqlParameter parameterHourlyPay = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@HourlyPay", Value = employee.HourlyPay };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterHourlyPay);
            SqlParameter parameterHoursWorked = new SqlParameter() { ParameterName = "@HoursWorked", Value = employee.HoursWorked };
            cmd.Parameters.Add(parameterHoursWorked);
        }

        con.Open();
        cmd.ExecuteNonQuery();
    }
}
```

The proxy method generated is as follows:-

```
 public void SaveEmployee(int Id, string Name, string Gender, DateTime DOB, EmployeeType Type, int AnnualSalary, int HourlyPay, int HoursWorked);
```

Although, it should be as:-

```
 public void SaveEmployee(Employee employee);
```

Could anyone tell me the reason behind this?

Comment: Your operation contract is expecting `EmployeeInfo`, but you say you expect the proxy to use `Employee`?  Is that a typo?  Is the class being passed in something that is in the assembly or referenced assembly?  Perhaps the Add Service Reference tool can't find the object, and is inferring the parameters (though that doesn't seem likely).

Comment: How you are generating your proxy? svcUtil.exe or directly going through service reference?